# Windows 10 Start Menu - Roaming Profiles

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, roaming-profiles

We have Windows 10 1703 Education edition and have been battling with the start menu (as well as many other bugs) for a while now.

What have I done?

GPO's

- Set Mandatory start menu xml
- Set excludedprofiledirs to:

-

```
AppData\LocalLow;
$Recycle.Bin;
OneDrive;
WorkFolders;
AppData\Local\Comms;
AppData\Local\ConnectedDevicesPlatform;
AppData\Local\Google;
AppData\Local\GroupPolicy;
AppData\Local\Mozilla;
AppData\Local\Packages;
AppData\Local\Publishers;
AppData\Local\PeerDistRepub;
AppData\Local\Temp;
AppData\Local\VirtualStore;
AppData\Local\Winternals;
AppData\Local\Adobe;
AppData\Local\Apple;
AppData\Local\AppleComputer;
AppData\Local\Autodesk;
AppData\Local\Chromium;
AppData\Local\CrashDumps;
AppData\Local\NVIDIA;
AppData\Local\NVIDIACorporation;
AppData\Local\Skype;
AppData\Local\WebEx;
AppData\Local\Foxit Reader;
AppData\Local\Macromedia;
AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation;
AppData\Local\Real;
AppData\Local\DropBox;
AppData\Local\Vmware;
AppData\Local\Windows Live;
AppData\Local\CrashDumps;
AppData\Local\Citrix;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\AppV;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Credentials;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Feeds;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Feeds Cache;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\GameDVR;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Group Policy;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\InputPersonalization;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\InstallAgent;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\PenWorkspace;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\PlayReady;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Vault;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\UPPS;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\1033;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\ActionCenterCache;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Application Shortcuts;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\GameExplorer;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\IECompatCache;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\IECompatUaCache;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Notifications;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\OfflineFiles;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PRICache;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Ringtones;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\RoamingTiles;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Safety;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\SchCache;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\SettingSync;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\CLR_v4.0;
AppData\Local\Microsoft\CLR_v4.0_32
```

The issue appears to be at the point of saving the tiledata folders. They do not upload to the user profile. I have a workaround script which "sometimes" works on logoff which stops the tiledata service and copies the files to the correct location on the profile server. During login however, the tiledata files are not always activated and restarting the tiledata service then fixes this.

Next, the restart of this service then shows the icons in the start menu but not in the order of the xml file!

Any ideas?

Comment: @andselisk - Using third-party software like Classic Shell isn't possible in every environment.  If you don't have an answer to this question, or a comment that direct the author to an actual solution, it is best to keep a suggestion like that to yourself.  While there are cases where a response that indicates a user do the "industry accepted standard" is appropriate using Classic Shell isn't industry accepted.

Comment: @Adsy2010 - If you get rid of the mandatory start menu group policy does this behavior still exhibit itself?  What is your AD running on?

Comment: blimey, fireworks! @Ramhound we are literally just completing the upgrade from server 2012 to 2016 for the domain controllers. The mandatory start menu xml is applied to a group and when not applied, the default icons appear at login. As they are all new app icons, it shows them. I havent tested since the logoff policy was put in place

Comment: @andeselisk thanks, we are considering it as a possible option for the future if windows 10 fails badly for us.

Comment: Just want to point out that AppData\Local should already be excluded from roaming profiles. It's not something that you have to specify. I'm not sure if it is causing any harm to specify all those folders. Is it accurate to say that your question is "Why isn't a custom start menu layout working?"

Comment: The tile data folder is located in the local folder. To exclude everything EXCEPT the appdata\local\tiledata folder you cannot exclude appdata\local @appleoddity

Comment: AppData\Local is ALREADY excluded. AppData\Local does NOT roam. If you are trying to include it somehow, you might be breaking things. Your custom start menu layout should be applied by group policy and it takes care of the rest. I'm not sure why you are trying to manipulate files or mess with what is roaming? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c09b60e5-adb4-4a38-8700-ca7351a2ab88/excluding-default-folders-from-roaming-profile?forum=winserverGP  and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/customize-windows-10-start-screens-by-using-group-policy

Comment: If your issue is that the custom tiles that users are creating aren't roaming, and you are saying that data is stored on appdata\local - then this is perfectly normal. As I said, AppData\Local doesn't roam, and you can't change that. What you need to do is to use enterprise state roaming through Azure or Windows Live accounts. I believe that will roam the start layout.

Comment: As a school with 4 DC's using local ADFS, live accounts are a no go and Azure is not included without paying even more out. The tiles don't roam unless you force them too. and yes you can change the roaming state of files by modifying the group policy to NOT exclude files/folders. @Appleoddity (see policy `administrative templates > system > user profiles > exclude directories in roaming profile`)

Comment: I left an answer below for you. In regards to your comment about Azure. I just want to make sure you know that a huge subset of Office 365 services is available to schools 100% free, I believe this includes all the active directory premium and enterprise state roaming stuff: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/education/products/office/default.aspx  Something to definitely be aware of, as it's an extremely awesome program.

Comment: I appreciate the comments made here, we are rolling back to 7 for the time being. Too many issues with Windows 10 to be viable in an enterprise environment using roaming profiles at this time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have concerns about why your custom Windows 10 Start Menu tile layouts are not roaming with the user's roaming profile. You have made some attempts to force this by copying data that is located under the user's Appdata\Local folder.

**It is normal, and expected behavior that the user's Start Menu tile layout does NOT roam with the roaming profiles option.**

The Appdata\Local folder is a part of the user profile that doesn't roam when you enable Roaming Profiles. In Windows XP this folder was called "Local Settings." It is now Appdata\Local. It is a local folder designed to hold localized data that is not safe to roam. On the other hand Appdata\Roaming is the folder where application data is placed that is safe and will roam.

The policy you mentioned, "Exclude directories in roaming profiles" is self-explanatory and states the following specifically:

> By default, the Appdata\Local and Appdata\LocalLow folders and all
>   their subfolders such as the History, Temp, and Temporary Internet
>   Files folders are excluded from the user's roaming profile.

And, more specifically, to the point:

> Note: You cannot use this policy setting to include the default
>   folders in a roaming user profile.

It is problematic in multiple ways to try to roam data under the Appdata\Local folder, and this folder CANNOT be included in the user's roaming profile.

As you have discovered, the tile layout is stored in a database under the user's Appdata\Local folder. So, it will not roam with the user's roaming profile. It may be possible to script or force this in someway, but that would be unsupported by Microsoft.

You might think this is strange, but it shouldn't be surprising.

Microsoft has indicated their direction is "cloud first" and have built Windows 10 with that in mind. Windows 10 is now moving to what is called "Modern Apps," and the use of legacy Roaming Profiles is now considered bad practice and is no longer recommended in today's mobile first world. Using Roaming Profiles will become more problematic and less effective as time goes on. Instead, Microsoft has delivered to us new roaming technologies to use.

See the following quote from a [Microsoft Employee](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/profile/jeff%20patterson%20-%20msft/?ws=usercard-mini) found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9a6427b9-571f-4255-afa4-5e91b9f1cb70/folder-redirection-deployment?forum=win10itpronetworking):

> Regarding Roaming User Profiles (RUP) support, RUP is supported on
>   Windows 10 but we’re no longer investing in new features. We do plan
>   to deprecate RUP in the future but the timing has not been determined.
>   Our recommendation is to use our modern solutions for roaming user
>   data:   ·         For settings and application data, use UE-V or
>   Enterprise State Roaming (ESR) ·         For user data, use Work
>   Folders or OneDrive for Business

Microsoft has no intention of continuing to support legacy technologies that don't fit in with today's enterprise needs, and are contrary to their longterm business goals.

Comment: further down the comments on the page you found your roaming user profile quote it states that is not the case and the microsoft employee saying this, was incorrect. I have read that post too.

Comment: please ignore my previous comment, I had seen the reference in a separate post, not that particular one